# Автоматизация тестирования Jenkins

Tags: java, android, jenkins

Написал проект залил на гит установил `Jenkins`. Взял этот проект из git, как теперь на `Jenkins` запустить тесты?

Comment: Поясните, какие тесты вы имеете ввиду. Если, к примеру, у вас сборка идёт средствами `maven`, то тесты есть часть сборки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать Job. Она может быть как `Freestyle job`, так и `Pipeline`. [Официальное руководство](https://jenkins.io/user-handbook.pdf) по Jenkins.

Еще вам понадобится JDK (в Jenkins можно установить автоматически) и Android SDK. Потом с помощью вашего `Gradle` файла и Jenkins [sh()](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) запускать таски(это относится к `Pipeline`, для `Freestyle job` примеры в ссылках).

```groovy
 sh './gradlew compileDebugSources'
 sh './gradlew assembleDebug'
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Простой Pipeline для Android](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/01/08/moving-from-buddybuild-for-android/)
- [Простой Pipeline для Java приложения](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/)
- [Раздел про Android на официальном сайте](https://jenkins.io/solutions/android/)
- [Настройка Jenkins для Android разработки](https://pamartinezandres.com/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-integration-server-for-android-development-ubuntu-jenkins-sonarqube-43c1ed6b08d3)
- [Пример Pipiline 1](https://gist.github.com/amaksoft/b17408303d69c71498eaa39ea2ee3b01)
- [Пример Pipiline 2](https://gist.github.com/tonespy/dd1afbb9d62d879d0ae6d8136ea4e4f6)

Comment: всё так только тесты я запустил в отделе build gradle task написал clean test тд тп )и всё всё заработало